# Iphone to create slideshow in app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

I want to create a static iPhone app,where it's contents are around 20 pages.
For that i have to create 20 different views using storyboard.

My question is, Is there any other technique to create such an app,where i can save my time?

Each screen transaction depends on user tap.

Comment: Just use a Swipe gesture and scrollview with your 20 pages on it (or) you can use page view controller also

Comment: but for this i have to create 20 pages.............. and i dn't want to create that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `UIScrollView`.

```
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

for (int i==0;i<=pagenumber;i++) {

    UIView *objUIView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*320,0,320,480)];

    [scrollView addSubview:objUIView];

    [objUIView release];
}

scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(PageNumber*320, 80);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scrollview. Create a scrollView and get its paging enabled.

```
scrollView.pagingEnabled=YES;
```

after that you can define the no of vieews to be 20 or whatsoever of your wish.